# Nuxt3 route page change loads previous page's data

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a project that lays out pages like this,

```
library.vue
library
   assets/[assetId]
   favoite/[assetId]
```

I have a Assets component in Library.vue template, Assets contains NuxtPage that loads the internal pages and navigation.

Also in NuxtPage I am using a useLazyQuery to load graphql data for the specific dynamic pages.

Now the problem is when change the URL form assets to favorite page or vice versa. The current assetId route gets called but also previous API call also gets called.